# How to make value become 0 in textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a dice game where you roll dice. When you roll a number that number adds to your total score. But when you roll a 1 you lose your total score and it switches to the other player. You can also hold to switch player.

As it is right now it become 0 after getting a 1 the first time. My problem is that when you switch back to the original starter player the score that was there before comes back. Like it does not stay the value of 0 but only looks like it.

```js
var swithcing = false;
var current1 = 0;
var total1 = 0;
var current2 = 0;
var total2 = 0;

function roll() {
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var player1score = document.querySelector('.player1total');
  var player1curent = document.querySelector('.player1');
  var player2score = document.querySelector('.player2total')
  var player2curent = document.querySelector('.player2')
  if (randomnumber == 1) {
    swithcing = !swithcing;
    player1score.innerHTML = 0;
    player1curent.innerHTML = 0;
    player2curent.innerHTML = 0;
  }
  if (randomnumber == 1 && swithcing == false) {
    player2score.innerHTML = 0;
  }
  if (swithcing == true) {
    current2 += randomnumber;
    player2score.innerHTML = current2;
    player2curent.innerHTML = randomnumber;
  }
  if (swithcing == false) {
    current1 += randomnumber;
    player1score.innerHTML = current1;
    player1curent.innerHTML = randomnumber;
  }
}

function hold() {
  swithcing = !swithcing;
}
```

```html
<h1>Player 1</h1>
<h2 class="player1"></h2>
<h3 class="player1total"></h3>


<h1>Player 2</h1>
<h2 class="player2"></h2>
<h3 class="player2total"></h3>

<input type="button" onclick="roll()" value="Roll Dice!" />
<input type="button" onclick="hold()" value="Hold!" />
```

Comment: Your markup doesn't seem to contain a textbox. If it is there, you can [read how it is used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Comment: You never reset `current1` or `current2` to 0, only the `innerHTML` of the headers(?).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look something like this

```js
let switching = false;
let current1 = 0;
let total1 = 0;
let current2 = 0;
let total2 = 0;
let randomnumber = 0
const player1score = document.querySelector('.player1total');
const player1current = document.querySelector('.player1');
const player2score = document.querySelector('.player2total');
const player2current = document.querySelector('.player2');

function roll() {
  randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  //console.log(randomnumber);
  //logic for normal rolls
  if(randomnumber > 1){
    if(switching==true){
        current2=randomnumber;//set to number rolled
        total2+=randomnumber;//sum to total score
    } else {
        current1=randomnumber;//set to number rolled
        total1+=randomnumber;//sum to total score
    }
  }
  //logic if player loses
  if (randomnumber == 1) {
    //switch
    switching = !switching;
    //if switches to player 2
    current1=0;//reset
    current2=0;//reset
    if(switching==true){
        //console.log("Player 2 selected");
        total2+=total1//total becomes player 1 previous total
        total1=0;//player 1 total resets
    } else {
        //console.log("Player 1 selected");
        total1+=total2//total becomes player 2 previous total
        total2=0;//player 2 total resets
    }
  }
  player1score.textContent = total1;
  player1current.textContent = current1;
  player2current.textContent = current2;
  player2score.textContent = total2;
}

function hold() {
  switching = !switching;
  player1score.textContent = total1;
  player1current.textContent = 0;
  player2current.textContent = 0;
  player2score.textContent = total2;
}
```

```html
<h1>Player 1</h1>
<h2 class="player1"></h2>
<h3 class="player1total"></h3>


<h1>Player 2</h1>
<h2 class="player2"></h2>
<h3 class="player2total"></h3>

<input type="button" onclick="roll()" value="Roll Dice!" />
<input type="button" onclick="hold()" value="Hold!" />
```